# ionic 2 check if user already logged in with angularfire2

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I did facebook login to my app and I'm trying to check if the user logged in then go to HomePage,if not go to loginPage.
I did it with firebase but I'm trying to do that with angularfire2
that's my code with firebase (I want it in angularfire2)

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
   var that=this;
  if (user) {
    if(this.reg_boolean=="true"){
      console.log("regCompleted");  
       this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage,{
       dep:this.department,year:this.year,semester:this.semester

    })
      this.rootPage=TabsPage;
    }
    else{
    this.rootPage = SignupPage;
    }
    console.log("I'm here! HomePage");
  } else {
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    console.log("I'm here! LoginPage");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work in `app.component.ts` file.

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2'; // import this, duh

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any;
  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;
  userName:string;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
              public af: AngularFire,
              public authService: AuthenticationService) { // used for logout

     this.initializeApp();

     // Listen for auth sub
     af.auth.subscribe(user => {
        this.rootPage = user ? HomePage : LoginPage;
     });
     ....
```

So basically get listening on the subscribe and change the `rootPage` based on the value passed into the var `user`. You can do a `console.log()` on `user` if you want to be more specific with the redirection.

Comment: I will try that,how to use in the authService? it's provider in your project?how do you logout? i have facebook login.